# Formatting an entered time string on the user's behalf

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, formatting, datetime-format

I want to record a user-entered time, but I don't want the user to have to worry about entering things such as ":" or ".". The only times entered will be around 7-8 minutes, and any number of seconds with a possible decimal point, but I would like the user to just be able to enter something like `7234` and have it format to `7:23.4`.

Any ideas or hints would be great!

Comment: Given any number of seconds and possible decimal point, what if the user meant to enter `72:34`? Does your formatter handle this as `7234:00.000`, `723:04.000000`, `72:34` or `7:23.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a clever use of

`– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

(see the documentation for the [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate)).

If you know for certain that the time will always be <10 minutes, then after the first numeric entry, add `:` and after the next two add `.`. However, it may be easier to use different fields for minutes and seconds. For instance, what if the user enters 713... how would you parse this? 7:13 or 7:1.3?

Comment: I was thinking that the number should always be 4 digits, >10 minutes would be to high of a number. But i guess i can see the problem, maybe i should just have 3 text fields, minutes, seconds, and mili. Although deepak's suggestion is nice, i think its a little bit more work, but ill see what i can do between the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to recommend an alternate approach. Since you can't predict where the `:` and `.` should go if the user enters a continuous piece of text. You should rather present a picker view when the user taps on the text field and let the user pick the time. This works by setting a `UIPickerView` object as the `inputView` of the `UITextField`. Ideally an easier tool would have been a `UIDatePicker` but it doesn't have seconds in any of its modes. So you will have to create a picker view with 3 components - minutes, seconds and milliseconds. You will have to become its data source and the delegate and provide all the possible values for the three components. You will also need to add a view (a `UIToolbar` perhaps) with a button that `resignsFirstResponder` for the text field.

Personally I am biased towards this approach but it is only available since iOS 3.2 which should be a part of your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not absolutely necessary to use only one textfield, you could perhaps use more? 
From left to right, the first one represents the minutes, the second one has 2 places and represents seconds and the third (and last) one represents numbers beyond the decimal point. Then simply switch between them as the user enters the numbers.

You might also want to check out how it's cleverly done for money (which has similar problems to time 100 could be 1.00, or 10.0 or 100) in a Slovenian app called [Toshl](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/toshl/id384083725?mt=8) - when adding expenses.